# Multiply Adjacent Elements

Tags: python, tuples, multiplication

I have a tuple of integers such as `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and I want to produce the tuple `(1*2, 2*3, 3*4, 4*5)` by multiplying adjacent elements. Is it possible to do this with a one-liner?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short and sweet. Remember that `zip` only runs as long as the shortest input.

```
print tuple(x*y for x,y in zip(t,t[1:]))
```

Comment: @nneonneo @Paul Manta Not so good. ``t[1:]`` creates a new object, the ``zip(t,t[1:])`` creates one object more, and ``for x,y in zip(t,t[1:])`` needs unpacking of each element of the zipped object to the two identifiers ``x`` and ``y``

Comment: If it matters to you, use `izip` and `islice`. Tuple unpacking is cheap, and avoiding it just to save a few microseconds is not worth it.

Comment: @nneonneo ``izip`` or ``islice`` need to be imported (however ``islice`` is a good idea I think). You say in another comment that indexing tuples is expensive; ``zip``, probably ``izip`` too it seems to me, builds tuples of two elements, it is a pity to build objects that need to be unpacked just after. On the contrary, tu[i] and tu[i+1] do access directly to elements

Comment: @eyquem: Under Python 3, this solution is about 35% faster (13.3ms vs. 20.6ms) for tuples of length 100000 than using indexing. (Note that under Python 3, `zip` is lazy like `izip`).

Comment: @nneonneo I don't know what means 35% faster. I understand saying  ``izip`` runs in 35% time less than ``indexing``. In Python 2, it is 32 %.

Comment: Yes, I benchmarked on Python 3, where `zip` behaves like 2.x `izip`.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> print tuple(t[i]*t[i+1] for i in range(len(t)-1))
(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

Not the most pythonic of solutions though.

Comment: @Volatility See my comment to Eugenie's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If t is your tuple:

```
>>> tuple(t[x]*t[x+1] for x in range(len(t)-1))
(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

And another solution with lovely map:

```
>>> tuple(map(lambda x,y:x*y, t[1:], t[:-1]))
(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

Edit:
And if you worry about the extra memory consuption of the slices, you can use islice from itertools, which will iterate over your tuple(thx @eyquem):

```
>>> tuple(map(lambda x,y:x*y, islice(t, 1, None), islice(t, 0, len(t)-1)))
(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

Comment: The first one is basic good. The second isn't so good because ``t[1:]`` creates an entirely new object and ``t[:1]`` creates also an entirely new object: it's time and memory consuming, that may be an inconvenient if the tuple is very large. - The first solution is access to elements of an existing tuple, index accesses are very fast (as far as I know)

Comment: @eyquem for small tuples, the indexing is all (relatively expensive) Python calls whereas iteration likely involves more C code. (Cue complaint about premature optimization, etc...). And if you really care that much about not copying the tuple, you can use `izip` and `islice`.

Comment: @nneonneo Indexing tuples is expensive ? I'd like to know more

Comment: @eyquem: Indexing tuples is more Python operations, that's all.

Comment: @nneonneo Mmmmm... What do you call more operations ?

Comment: @eyquem: Benchmark them! And let me know what you find. (Also, it really needs to use `xrange` or else it will be extra-slow ;) )

Comment: @nneonneo OK, I will see that some day. Than,k you

Comment: @nneonneo I did. I couldn't wait another day. You're right, ``zip`` isn't so slow I thought. Evidently, ``izip`` is the best. See the benchmark in my answer, please. Upvote for you

Comment: @Eugenie See my comparison of times in my edit. nneonneo is right, indexing and use of zip are equivalent

Answer (score 3):

I like the [recipes from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    xs, ys = tee(iterable)
    next(ys)
    return izip(xs, ys)

print [a * b for a, b in pairwise(range(10))]
```

Result:

```
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tu = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

it = iter(tu).next
it()
print tuple(a*it() for a in tu)
```

I timed various code:

```
from random import choice
from time import clock
from itertools import izip

tu = tuple(choice(range(0,87)) for i in xrange(2000))

A,B,C,D = [],[],[],[]

for n in xrange(50):

    rentime = 100

    te = clock()
    for ren in xrange(rentime): # indexing
        tuple(tu[x]*tu[x+1] for x in range(len(tu)-1))
    A.append(clock()-te)

    te = clock()
    for ren in xrange(rentime): # zip
        tuple(x*y for x,y in zip(tu,tu[1:]))
    B.append(clock()-te)

    te = clock()
    for ren in xrange(rentime): #i ter
        it = iter(tu).next
        it()
        tuple(a*it() for a in tu)
    C.append(clock()-te)

    te = clock()
    for ren in xrange(rentime): # izip
        tuple(x*y for x,y in izip(tu,tu[1:]))
    D.append(clock()-te)


print 'indexing ',min(A)
print 'zip      ',min(B)
print 'iter     ',min(C)
print 'izip     ',min(D)
```

result

```
indexing  0.135054036197
zip       0.134594201218
iter      0.100380634969
izip      0.0923947037962
```

izip is better than zip : - 31 %

My solution isn't so bad (I didn't think so by the way): -25 % relatively to zip, 10 % more time than champion izip

I'm surprised that indexing isn't faster than zip : nneonneo is right, zip is acceptable

Comment: When I change `range` to `xrange` in this line `tuple(tu[x]*tu[x+1] for x in range(len(tu)-1))` and increase tuple size to 200,000 indexing performs 30% times faster than zip on my machine. Though, izip and iter are the fastest and very close.

Comment: @Akavall @nneonneo Oh I was stupid to let ``range``. You are right, Akavall, it improves. I did the same as you (200,000) and I got 16 for ``zip``, 13 for ``indexing`` and ``iter`` and 10 for ``izip``. The longer is the tuple, the worse is ``zip``. That means that the construct of the new object by ``zip`` is heavy. The fact that ``izip`` remains the best means that the unpacking isn't really time consuming. However, 10 compared to 13 is now only 23 % less time, not 32 or 35%.