# Multiply adjacent elements of list and add them

Tags: python, list

I want to successively multiply adjacent element of the list and add the multiplication:

- `([1,2,3,4])` should perform `(1*2+2*3+3*4)`, and
- `[1,2,3]` I want to get `8` because `(1*2)+(2*3)`

Comment: Something is not clear in what you are asking, either your examples are wrong - or you are not *multiplying*. 1 times 2 times 3 is 6, not 8.

Comment: Essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/14916957/1907098, except you `sum` the resulting list.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `fold` or `zip` ...

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sum(mylist[i] * mylist[i + 1] for i in range(len(mylist) - 1))
20
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```python
x=[1,2,3,4]
print sum(a*b for a,b in zip(x, x[1:]))
#prints 20
```

Comment: +1. You can shed the `[:-1]`, `print sum(a*b for a,b in zip(x, x[1:]))` produces the same result

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`pairwise` itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
>>> sum(a * b for (a, b) in pairwise([1, 2, 3, 4]))
20
>>> sum(a * b for (a, b) in pairwise([1, 2, 3]))
8
```

> What I need to change if want `function([1,2,3,4])` perform `(1*2*3*4)`?

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul
>>> reduce(mul, [1, 2, 3, 4])
24
```

Comment: What I need to chenge if want function([1,2,3,4]) perform (1*2*3*4)?

Answer (score 1):

Function using [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
def my_math(lst):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x[0]*x[1], zip(lst,  lst[1:])))

>>> my_math([1,2,3])
8
>>> my_math([1,2,3,4])
20
>>> my_math([1,2,3,4,5])
40
```

Comment: That's what I thought "multiply elements" meant too, but look at the examples OP gives in the question body.

Comment: @ersran9 You mean the `map(mul, ...)` one? `mul` takes two arguments, and—sadly—does not support passing a single iterable.

Comment: @poke Well, what I wanted to know was why `map(mul, *zip(..))` wouldn't provide two arguments to `mul` instead of a `tuple`.

Comment: @ersran9 `*zip()` only makes the return value of the whole zip expand into multiple arguments, so you are essentially calling `map(mul, zip_0, zip_1, zip_2, ...)` where each `zip_i` is still a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [88]: mylist = [1,2,3,4]

In [89]: sum(itertools.imap(lambda t: operator.mul(*t), itertools.izip(mylist, itertools.islice(mylist, 1, len(mylist)))))
Out[89]: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

A generator expression without any list slices/copies

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sum(mylist[i-1] * j for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if i)
20
```